# Classes aren't converted to JS GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

When I launched the Project it launched finely but when I tried to change a button name and save.It didn't change the value on the browser any ideas why is that happening ??
is that a caching problem or something ?
*hint I'm using `Google App Engine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem was when I tried to load another page I forget to assign this parmeter

```
?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

The gwt port which is responsible to synchronize any changes